# How to uninstall minitest from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uninstallation, minitest

I'm using Ruby 2.2.0p0, and Rails 4.2.0. The Rails application is currently defaulting to using minitest, even though there's no testing gems mentioned in the Gemfile. For example, I have `rake test` in my rake tasks, and a `test` folder.

I can see how to install RSpec-rails. But what, if anything, do I need to do to uninstall minitest?

The only thing the RSpec-Rails [README](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) has is

> Once installed, RSpec will generate spec files instead of Test::Unit
>   test files when commands like rails generate model and rails generate
>   controller are used.

Comment: minitest is the default if you have no others installed. Install one of the others and you should be good to go. Note that some of the others actually use test::unit under the covers, though - they're just a different DSL on top of it.

Comment: Minitest is part of ruby's core http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest.html

Answer (score 11):

It seems to me that in your case it not necessary to uninstall minitest, just add rspec to your Gemfile and start using it. However I recommend you to make RSpec as your default test framework.
Just add to *config/application.rb* next line:

```
config.generators.test_framework :rspec
```

That's it. Now Rails knows that you use RSpec and when you use Rails generators, it will add appropriate RSpec templete files, not Minitest ones. If you have test folder in your application (it's used by Minitest and Test::Unit) you can delete it now.

Comment: Don't forget `config.generators.integration_tool :rspec`! Otherwise, generators will still create `test_unit` integration tests.

Comment: And as of RSpec 4.0, [both of these config options will be provided out-of-the-box](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/be3ae66f25863e05336d7fb54b363a833179aa4c/lib/rspec-rails.rb#L20-L21).